# two samples z test in Python

Tags: hypothesis-testing, python, z-test

Does Scipy have a z test to compare the mean of two samples?
I searched [this page](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/stats.html) but couldn't find one.

Comment: I haven't used Python for Stats in a little while but, as I recall, it's best to use **Statsmodels** instead of **Scipy.Stats**.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about available functions in Python.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Statsmodels has a `ztest` function that allows you to compare two means, assuming they are independent and have the same standard deviation. See the documentation [here](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/stable/generated/statsmodels.stats.weightstats.ztest.html#statsmodels.stats.weightstats.ztest)

If you need to compare means from distributions with different standard deviation, you should use `CompareMeans.ztest_ind`. See documentation [here](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.stats.weightstats.CompareMeans.ztest_ind.html).

There might be other functions I'm missing so search through the documentation!

Answer (score 9):

No, but this wouldn't be that hard to write a function for:

```
def twoSampZ(X1, X2, mudiff, sd1, sd2, n1, n2):
    from numpy import sqrt, abs, round
    from scipy.stats import norm
    pooledSE = sqrt(sd1**2/n1 + sd2**2/n2)
    z = ((X1 - X2) - mudiff)/pooledSE
    pval = 2*(norm.sf(abs(z)))
    return round(z, 3), round(pval, 4)
```

where X1 = $\bar{X1}$, X2 = $\bar{X2}$, mudiff = null = $\mu_1 - \mu_2$, sd1 = $\sigma_1$, sd2 = $\sigma_2$, n1 = $n_1$ and n2 = $n_2$. So, going off of [this](http://www.cliffsnotes.com/math/statistics/univariate-inferential-tests/two-sample-z-test-for-comparing-two-means) example:

```
z, p = twoSampZ(28, 33, 0, 14.1, 9.5, 75, 50)
print z, p
```

Comment: Just a little tip: `1 - norm.cdf` can be replaced in numpy using `norm.sf`, which gives better precision.